# How to quickly setup a good "style" in the terminal

Tags: ssh, gnome-terminal

Before upgrading ubuntu I had a good configuration in my gnome terminal and in my previous job I had the same scheme when connecting ssh via putty: username in bold, executables in bold green, folders in bold and other things. 
Unfortunately I think I choose to overwrite my user settings and I lost all.
Is there a place where to download a good settings file?

Edit:

[image]

The first three lines are the result that I'd like to obtain. The last line is the result that I got after editing .bashrc as follows:

```
# color names for readibility
reset=$(tput sgr0)
bold=$(tput bold)
black=$(tput setaf 0)
red=$(tput setaf 1)
green=$(tput setaf 2)
yellow=$(tput setaf 3)
blue=$(tput setaf 4)
magenta=$(tput setaf 5)
cyan=$(tput setaf 6)
white=$(tput setaf 7)
user_color=$cyan
[ "$UID" -eq 0 ] && { user_color=$red; }
PS1='\[\e]0;\w\a\]\n\[\e[32m\]\u@\h \[\e[33m\]\w\[\e[0m\]\$ '
```

Comment: I find the default one a rather good one!

Comment: my default one is monochrome without any bold text or anything. Searching the web I found that probably I just need to alias ls --color=auto and few stuff like that. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/31695/how-to-make-the-terminal-display-usermachine-in-bold-letters

Answer (score 2):

You could go to preferences>>colors to change the style, though I am not sure this is the answer you want.